# get descent li anchor tag text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have markup of `ul` and `li`. what I need to do is get text value from direct descentc `li a` text only. Expected result is a,b,c. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67x0q5pj/)

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
$('ul').first().find(' > li').each(function(){
alert($('a',this).text())   
})      
})
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><a>a</a>
<ul>
<li><a>a1</a></li>
<li><a>a2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a>b</a></li>
<li><a>c</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.children()` instead which travels a single level down the DOM tree. Created a snippet for you:

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul').first().children('li').each(function() {
    alert($(this).children('a').text())
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>a</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>a1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>a2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>b</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>c</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```